# Getting error when referencing a div id from another file using React/D3

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, d3.js

I'm trying to make an on click event for a D3 graph so that when you click on a node it displays a bunch of information of the node on the right side of the page. The graph and page are both made on separate files, and the div is created alongside the page, not the graph: `<div id="nodeDescription"></div>`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Graph } from '../Graph';
import CSS from '../CSS/NodeLink.module.css';

const { gridContainer, titles, node, chord, info } = CSS;

const Visualizations2 = ({ data }) => {
    return (
        <div className={gridContainer}>
            <h1 id="one" className={`${titles} ${node}`}>Node-edge graph of email network</h1>
            <Graph data={data} type={1} />
            <div id="nodeDescription"></div>
            <h1 id="two" className={`${titles} ${chord}`}>Chord graph of email network</h1>
            <Graph data={data} type={2}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Visualizations2;
```

I already have an on click event in the D3 graph, but now I just want to extend its functionality by making it also display information about the node in the `nodeDescription` div.

```
var infoDiv = document.getElementById("nodeDescription");

// ...

    function clicked(event, d) {
        infoDiv.html(
            "Name: " + d.name + "</br>" +
            "Job title: " + d.job.name + "</br>" + 
            "User ID: " + d.id + "</br>" + 
            "Number of Emails sent: " + stats[d.id] + "</br>" +
            "Email: " + d.email
            )
        highlight(d);
        const {x, y} = d;
        event.stopPropagation();
        svg.transition().duration(750).call(
          zoomAttr.transform,
          zoomIdentity
            .translate(width / 2, height / 2)
            .scale(2)
            .translate(-x, -y),
          pointer(event, svg.node())
        );
    };
```

When I click on a node now, I get the error `TypeError: infoDiv.html is not a function`. It does seem to work fine if I reference a div that was created in the same file, for example:

```
var tooltipDiv = select(container)
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", tooltip)
    .style("opacity", 0);
```

Trying to console log the `infoDiv` variable returns [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXuXm.png) so I do think it works, since [it is the same div as in the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nS9Vy.png). I'm just not sure why it breaks if I try to call `infoDiv.html(...)` when I was able to call `tooltipDiv.html(...)` in another function. I'm still relatively new to React/D3, so I would really appreciate some help in trying to figure this out. I want to have the stuff in the `infoDiv.html(...)` function being rendered [here, on the Lorem Ipsum placeholder.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAzT7.png)

Comment: `infoDiv` seems to be a plain-and-simple DOM element, and as such it does not have a `.html()` method. It looks like you are trying to use it as a jQuery object, or perhaps as something from D3. But that will not work, you first have to treat the DOM element to become wrapped/encapsulated using a jQuery or D3 object.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I added `infoDiv = select(container).append("div");` to the initial infoDiv declaration and that seems to work now.